# Extract nth line matching pattern and the next N lines

Tags: text-processing

There is a big file containing a pattern which is repeated periodically in the file, I want to extract just a specific pattern after certain values of occurrence as well as the next *N* lines.
Here is an example but the numbers before `members of the group` are not really existing.

input:

```
1 members of the group
...
...
2 members of the group
...
...
...
n members of the group
...
...
...
```

output:

```
85 members of the group
...
...
...
...
...
```

(85th match and the next 5 lines)

Comment: Please show some input data and expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way with `awk`:

```
awk -vN=85 -vM=5 'BEGIN{c=0}
/PATTERN/{c++
{if (c==N) {l=NR;last=NR+M}}
}{if (NR<=last && NR>=l) print}' infile
```

Where `N` is the *N*th line matching `PATTERN` and `M` is the number of lines that follow. It sets a counter and when the *N*th line matching is encountered it saves the line number. It then prints the lines from the current `NR` up to `NR`+*M*.

---

For the record, that's how you do it with `sed` (`gnu sed` syntax):

```
sed -nE '/PATTERN/{x;/\n{84}/{x;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;$!N;p;q};s/.*/&\n/;x}' infile
```

This is using the hold space to count.
Each time it encounters a line matching `PATTERN` it e`x`changes buffers and checks if there are *N-1* occurrences of `\n`ewline character in the hold buffer. If the check is successful it e`x`changes again, pulls in the next *M* lines with the `$!N` command and `p`rints the pattern space then `q`uits.
Otherwise it just adds another `\n`ewline char to the hold space and e`x`changes back.
This solution is less convenient as it quickly becomes cumbersome when *M* is a big number and requires some `printf`-fu to build up a `sed` script (not to mention the pattern and hold space limits with some `sed`s).

Comment: +1. Way faster than my solution.

Comment: @Kamil - thanks, you should really [avoid `while..read` when processing text](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). As a general rule, if you're using  `while..read` to process text then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing `awk` and using `sed` mostly for regex stuff, here is how I would do it:

- use `grep` to find the pattern, include line numers (`-n`)
- use `head` and `tail` (or `sed`) to get the 85th match (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file))
- isolate out the line number N using `cut`
- again, use `head` and `tail` (or `sed`) to get the Nth line of the original file and subsequent five lines

All this can be combined into one line. Dirty, probably slow, but will work with a minimal toolset.

#### Example

The following searches the rkhunter.log file and shows the third match of "basename" and subsequent four lines:

```
 /var/log$ tail rkhunter.log -n +$(grep -n 'basename' rkhunter.log|cut -d: -f1|tail -n +3|head -1)| head -5
```

#### Edit

Just saw @Wildcard's answer and the `-m` switch of `grep` is really much easier to use than my original solution. So here's another answer using `grep -m`

```
/var/log$ grep -m 3 -A 4 'basename'  rkhunter.log | tail -5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(exec <file.txt; grep -m 85 'PATTERN' | tail -n 1; head -n 5)
```

Obviously you can adjust the numbers as desired.

From `man grep`:

> ```
>    -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
>           Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the  input  is
>           standard  input  from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
>           output, grep ensures that the standard input  is  positioned  to
>           just  after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of
>           the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a  calling
>           process  to resume a search.
> ```

The above command takes advantage of this feature by using a subshell and setting the STDIN to the file that you intend to `grep`, so that this feature can work correctly.  Then you can simply catch the final (85th) instance with `tail -n 1`, and get the context lines you want with a separate call to `head`.

**Use this command if you *know* that the file has at least 85 instances of `PATTERN`**; in that case it will work perfectly.

If it *may* have less, the command will require some adjustment; in its current state it will simply print the final match with no trailing context lines if there are fewer matches than you've requested.

Answer (score 0):

That works in my bash:

```
{ T=85; N=5; c=0; while read line ; do echo "$line" | grep -c "members of the group" > /dev/null && c=$(($c+1)) ; [[ $c -eq $T ]] && { echo "$line"; break ;} ; done ; head -n $N ; } < input_file
```